# How to receive gps enabled/disabled?

Tags: android, gps, listener, broadcastreceiver

Hi I am trying to write a widget to show GPS Status.
In case user change GPS enable status I want my widget to be updated.

In other words: I want to **update** my widget **when gps status has changed**.
Do I need to write a BroadcastReceiver? If yes what action will it receive?

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Below are the methods I've used recently to do this, BUT I must warn you that I'm finding it (on at least one device) is returning true when there is no GPS hardware at all. Pass in a value like LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER. locationManager is an instance of LocationManager. Hopefully you will find this code useful, but although it works ok for me in my current scenario, I expect you will need to refine it.

```
// Checks whether the specified location provider is enabled on the device
public static boolean isLocationProviderEnabled(String provider)
{
    if ( locationManager.isProviderEnabled(provider) )
    {
        if (provider.toLowerCase().equals(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER))
        {
            return haveGPS();
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

// Checks whether the GPS hardware is present in the device
private static boolean haveGPS()
{
    PackageManager pmgr = SpondleApplication.getInstance().getPackageManager();
    boolean gotGPS = pmgr.hasSystemFeature("android.hardware.location.gps");
    return gotGPS;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.
My problem is actually receiving broadcasting of gps enabled/disabled.
I want to update my widget when gps status has changed.

Answer (score 0):

[You can try using GPSStatus.Listener:](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/GpsStatus.Listener.html%20Try%20using%20GPSStatus.Listener)